# inject web3 in electron-ethereum-react desktop application

Tags: web3js, truffle, testrpc, web3-providers, react

I am trying to make `ethereum-electron-react` application.

when I try to inject web3 it does not get detected.

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

console.log (Web3);
```

this shows an empty object

[image]
 even though I have already installed Web3.

node version -v8.9.4

[image]

[image]

any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Manish, How do you figure out how to create an electron ethereum app? Do you happen to have a guide or tips? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that replying the question with a question is a good practice (in this situation). If you have a specific question it would be better to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is how the electron app runs. It is serving content from the local storage.

Web3 will be injected only if the page was server from a web server:

[MetaMask Compatibility Guide](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md)

**Http(s) - Web Server Required**

> Due to browser security restrictions, we can't communicate with dapps
>   running on file://. Please use a local server for development.